# LTRIM() returns cells with "-1"

Tags: sql, ms-access, trim, data-cleaning

I have a set of rows that has a space entry by itself (" ") instead of being empty ("") and want to remove it.

I tried using `LTRIM(field)`, `RTRIM(field)`, `LTRIM(RTRIM(field))`, `RTRIM(LTRIM(field))`, and TRIM(field) - all of which replaces the cell with a "-1":

```
ID  | Location | Name 
--- | -------- | ---
 1  | A        | " "
 2  | B        | " "
 3  | C        | ""

Result (using trim)
ID  | Location | Name 
--- | -------- | ---
 1  | A        | -1
 2  | B        | -1
 3  | C        | ""
```

This seems like a simple operation, but I can't get it to remove the space. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Is it a space in the name field or something else that just looks like a space?

Comment: Did you try just `Trim`?

Comment: @MarkC. Yea TRIM() also returns -1 :(

Comment: @Nicarus It's a space in the value of the row, see post (edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim (Rtrim o Ltrim) are for removing space at the margin of the string .. in your sample seems you want remove space inside a string  in this case use `replace`

```
select id, location , Replace(Name, " ", "")
from your_table
```

Comment: @tkim90 - Not sure what other values you have in `Name` field, but know that the space(s) will be replaced in them as well.

Comment: @Nicarus I noticed that too, thanks for letting me know.